# CSS - Display a div when another is hovered

Tags: css

I am trying to display a div (.mydiv3) when another is hovered, but the div I want to display...

```css
.mydiv1, .mydiv2, .mydiv3 {
  display:none;
}

.trigger {
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px;
  color:teal;
}

.trigger:hover{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="trigger">
  Hover Trigger
</div>

<div class="mydiv1">
    Text Content 1
</div>

<div class="mydiv2">
    Text Content 2
</div>

<div class="mydiv3">
    Text Content 3
</div>
```

Is there a way to do this with CSS or is jQuery my best bet?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `~` in CSS to get the desired result. Check the snippet.

```css
.mydiv1, .mydiv2, .mydiv3 {
  display:none;
}

.trigger {
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px;
  color:teal;
}

.trigger:hover{
  background:red;
}

.trigger:hover~.mydiv3{
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="trigger">
  Hover Trigger
</div>

<div class="mydiv1">
    Text Content 1
</div>

<div class="mydiv2">
    Text Content 2
</div>

<div class="mydiv3">
    Text Content 3
</div>
```

Edit : With jQuery in case elements are not siblings

```
$(.trigger).on('mouseenter', function(){
   $('.mydiv3').show();
};

$(.trigger).on('mouseleave', function(){
   $('.mydiv3').hide();
};
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Tx for `~` useful

Comment: Is there an alternative to use if it is not a sibling?  For example, if the div that I want to display is within another seperate list?

Comment: If not sibling, You should go with jQuery with `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` methods

Answer (score 1):

You can use the general sibling selector for this.

```css
.mydiv1,
.mydiv2,
.mydiv3 {
  display: none;
}

.trigger {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  color: teal;
}

.trigger:hover {
  background: red;
}

.trigger:hover~.mydiv3 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="trigger">
  Hover Trigger
</div>

<div class="mydiv1">
  Text Content 1
</div>

<div class="mydiv2">
  Text Content 2
</div>

<div class="mydiv3">
  Text Content 3
</div>
```

Comment: That will show all sibling divs on hover; he wants to show only `.mydiv3`.

Comment: I thought he wanted to show all three, since he has a `display: none` on all of them. Missed that he mentioned only `.mydiv3`. Edited the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery:

```
$(".trigger").mouseout(function() {
    $(".mydiv3").hide();
})
.mouseover(function() {
    $(".mydiv3").show();
});
```